# How to insert html code from editor into MySQL database?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, html-editor

I have an html editor and I am trying to insert the html it generates into the database and then retrieve it in another page where is the SQL table. **I am using a table with one text field with asp 3.5**. Here is the code:

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Connection String  ");//I've tested the connection string and its working fine

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO ins (tes) VALUES ('" + Editor1.Content + "')", con);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

This is the error I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'font-size: 18pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: "arial","sans-serif";'>Whatever' at line 1

How can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more precise and indicate what goes wrong exactly ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you open yourself to a lot of SQL injection. Data coming from user should alwyas be checked and sanitized before ending up in the database.

Besides, using ASP.NET you need to remove any HTML tags from the postback because the framework checks for possible HTML injection coming from the browser.

After removing the tags (or replacing the `<` by something like `&lt;`) and converting back in the server, you can use something like:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO ins (tes) VALUES ('" + Editor1.Content.Replace("'", "''") + "')", con);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Although you should make parametrized queries.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use **parametrized query** instead, and never trust user data entry.please what is the type of `tes`, and could you clarify what is the error or the exception?

Comment: could you explain more please , and tes is a text

Comment: i mean parametrized query guarantee no sql injection , and no problems from the special characters.
http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2004/04/05/107456.aspx
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO ins (tes) VALUES (@text)", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@text", SqlDbType.Text);
cmd.Parameters["@text"].Value = txtTextField.Text;

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: yeah , you can use similar code (parametrized query) for mysql, just the syntax will be a little different, they use `(?)` instead of `(@)` to indicate that is a parameter.